# Sharing javascript code with mobile and main app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a desktop web app which I wrote in angularjs and has a node back end.

I am now looking at Ionic for my mobile needs and a lot of the web app (angularjs services)  will be reused.

What is the best way to restructure my services to enable the reuse of code?

My current structure of the projects is:

```
 --app (desktop)
 ---services
 ---etc
 --Server (nodejs)
 --mobileApp
```

Should I move the services folder higher up into a shared module or is there another way I can do this without restructure my main app?

Comment: A good solution should be migrate your codebase to ES6 and, using modules, you should be able to import services both from Desktop and Mobile App... Webpack and Babel should help you to do that legacy!

Comment: I see what you want to achieve. Perhaps the best way would be to have some folder called commonFeServices and have some config in your build scripts. I bet there will some services in D that you will not want in M and vice versa.

Comment: Would it work if I create an angular module and call it 'shared' and then pull in this module in the two different apps?